# Why did the Children of the Forest do something like this?

Tags: game-of-thrones

If I understand this correctly, all Children of the Forest are greenseers, which means that all of them can access the past and future.

Why would they go on and do something that will actively cause them to eventually lose?

S06E05 spoilers:

> I'm talking, of course, about creating the Night's King and the White Walkers. Which then spits in the face of the Children, as the Walkers come and kill them.

Comment: Can they see *everything*?

Comment: No all Children of the Forest are not Greenseers. Three eyed raven is the last Greenseer of the world. Bran is going to take his place however

Comment: @Jonah: Well, everything that is green... :-)

Comment: @Aegon: That's not what I understood. I understood that the Children are all seers; it's humans that are rarely wargs, and even rarer -- seers.

Comment: @MaybeBatman Hmm I suppose they said in show that all COTF are greenseers? Well at least in the books they are not but you are asking about show so I'd shut up ;)

Comment: @Aegon: I'm afraid that I haven't read the books. Just everything about them, all the spoilers and the plot points. Come to think about it, I guess you can say that I sort of read the books, digested in the minds of thousands and condensed into internet webpages. But yes, I'm talking about the show. But maybe I'm misremembering, and they didn't say that; maybe I'm confusing something from some video that I saw someone explaining things where they said that; but I got this idea somehow, that's for sure.

Comment: Ah well if we talk about books, It's simple deduction. Three eyed raven is explicitly called the last greenseer even though he lives with remaining COTF. If COTF were greenseers too, he would not be the last greenseer now, would he? It was only the wisest of the COTF who were greenseers (We can say like chieftains or something). But don't worry about it. Alot of things in the show lack internal logic.

Comment: @Aegon: I thought that greenseer meant specifically a human with greenseeing powers; whereas all the Children have this ability.

Comment: @MaybeBatman Just a small FYI: Be careful with those Silly online blogs who claim to know ASoIaF. They aren't very well informed themselves and often perpetuate the most "shocking" of fan theories. #ReadTheBooks

Comment: In the books, only a handful of the COTF are greenseers.  It also says that normal COTF are long-lived (not clear quite how long), but greenseers only live perhaps 200 years - unless they decide to get weirwood-rootified

Comment: Greenseers don't see every single outcome for all of time. The events you're talking about happened thousands of years after they created the white walkers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Because they needed a weapon. They were being slaughtered by The First Men.**

First of all. not all Children of the Forest are greenseers. They have some abilities, but definitely not all of them can see the past and future. The three eyed raven is the last one of the greenseers. Well, last before Bran.

When the First Men came into Westeros, 12 000 years before the invasion of Aegon the Conqueror, they started a war with the Children of the Forest which would last for 2 000 years.

Apparently, in the TV Show, they were being heavily defeated by the First Men and needed a weapon to fight back.

Comment: "We were at war. We were being slaughtered. Our sacred trees cut down. We needed to defend ourselves." The show answered the question literally seconds after the scene in question.

Comment: Just to add to this great answer: Even if the Children *did* have greenseers among them, we don't know what future those greenseers would've seen prior to the creation of their weapon.  It's possible that, without that weapon, the Children would've been completely wiped out in only a few years, rather than millennia.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're getting the information from that the Children of the Forest are greenseers. As for why they would create the Night King and the White Walkers, well this is answered directly by Leaf to Bran:

> BRAN: It was you. You made the White Walkers.
>   
> LEAF: **We were at war. We were being slaughtered. Our sacred trees cut down. We needed to defend ourselves.**
>   
> BRAN: From whom?
>   
> LEAF: **From you. From men.**
>   
> <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 6 Episode 5, "The Door"</sub>